# How to activate each link in the two-level menu tree using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

If there was only a one-level menu tree, activating and deactivating links would not be a problem.

```
<ul class="sidemenu">
 <li class="active"><a href="#">some title</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">some title</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">some title</a></li>
 etc ...
</ul>
```

```
$('.sidemenu').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.sidemenu li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I needed to solve the activation / deactivation of each link in the two-level menu tree, but I did not find the correct or working solution. I understand very well that this jquery code is suitable for a one-level menu.

I was looking everywhere for some good clues. My head is empty.

My jsfiddle code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/kukrik/d3pcrhnm/15/.

I would be very grateful if anyone has good advice or experiences to share.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kukrik/d3pcrhnm/15/ u should give click event to a

```
$('.sidemenu').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('a.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');      
});
```

and also update css

```
#sidebar nav ul li a.active  {
    background: rgba(239, 137, 31, 0.17);
}

#sidebar nav ul li a.active:hover {
    color: #181818;
    background: rgba(247, 148, 30, 0.27);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to Çağrı! Often a seemingly big problem turns out to be very simple. I once thought about this possible solution. It was this Css code that blocked my normal thinking.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kukrik/gzodabnm/11/